# FluentValidation IRuleBuilderOptions extension method - only run regex validator if value exists

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following FluentValidation extension method for validating phone numbers:

```cs
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MatchPhoneNumber<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> rule)
    => rule.Matches(@"^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$").WithMessage("Invalid phone number");
```

Which I call:

```cs
RuleFor(contact => contact.PhoneNumber).MatchPhoneNumber()
```

However, I only want the extension method to validate the phone number when the phone number string is not null/empty. I can do this by doing the following:

```cs
RuleFor(contact => contact.PhoneNumber)
    .MatchPhoneNumber()
    .When(contact => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.PhoneNumber));
```

but is there a way I can do this in the extension method itself?

Comment: can't you use `NotEmpty()` method

Comment: Wouldn't simply moving the `when` clause into the extension method be enough?

Comment: `NotEmpty()` validates the phone number and makes it invalid when nothing is entered, which is not the behavior wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your Regex to accept also empty strings like this:
`^$|^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$`

However, I have tried the latest version of FluentValidation (10.3.3) and it does NOT give any error if you pass a null or empty string to the `Matches` rule. In my example code here, I don't get any error in the result, despite PhoneNumber being Null:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var contact = new Contact();
        var contactValidator = new ContactValidator();
        var result = contactValidator.Validate(contact);
        Console.WriteLine(result.IsValid); // This returns true with null phone number
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ContactValidator : AbstractValidator<Contact>
{
    public ContactValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(contact => contact.PhoneNumber)
            .MatchPhoneNumber();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MatchPhoneNumber<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> rule)
        => rule.Matches(@"^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$").WithMessage("Invalid phone number");
}
```

Are you using a different way to define your validator?

Comment: I'm using a Blazor library, Blazored.FluentValidation, which appears to be using FluentValidation 10.2.1 as shown [here](https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation/blob/main/src/Blazored.FluentValidation/Blazored.FluentValidation.csproj#L30). So maybe something with that version is different? The only difference with my validator is I'm using `RuleForEach()` and then `RuleFor()` as my `Contact` is in a list of `Contacts`. I also instantiate PhoneNumber with an empty string:  `public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = "";` I used the regex you posted and that does seem to work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MatchPhoneNumber<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> rule, Func<T, bool> expression)
        => rule.Matches(@"^(1-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$").WithMessage("Invalid phone number").When(expression);
}
```